# Как привязать shell скрипт к контекстному меню в windows?

Tags: windows, shell, cygwin

Пару дней назад написал свой первый простейший скрипт .sh который делает 4 простейшие операции с файлами изображений. Resize, watermark, rename и отправляет все это по ftp. Скрипт работает на ура. Но хочется, чтоб в контекстном меню было пкм -> отправить -> скрипт. И нажимая, скрипт запускается и все делает, ибо вручную постоянно вбивать путь скрипта надоедает. Я уже это реализовал с bash от git (который поставляется вместе с установкой git). Там было просто, я просто вставил

```
--cd="%v." "d:/Work/scripts/sh/script.sh"
```

в аргументы файла C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\git-bash.exe и все работает. Но мне нужен именно Cygwin, ибо он поддерживает BC, чтоб высчитывать десятичные. Я для вызова cygwin и исполнения скрипта писал так

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -e /bin/xhere /bin/bash.exe "%V" "d:/Work/scripts/sh/script.sh"
```

Но вместо выполнения скрипта окно просто открывается с текущим каталогом и все больше никакой реакции. Я гуглил очень долго, но на русских форумах ответов не нашел, а на англоязычных писали, что надо добавить sh.exe перед адресом к скрипту. Но толку нет. Я подозреваю, что путь слишком длинный вот и не открывается. Но я попробовал вставить

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -e /bin/xhere /bin/bash.exe "%V" "d:/Work/scripts/sh/script.sh"
```

в Выполнить (win+R), но все равно нет реакции. Как это сделать? P.S. Я не знаю в правильный раздел форума, я написал.

Comment: У меня такое дома получалось, через пару дней доберусь до компьютера и посмотрю. (Тем временем может кто-то и ответит.)

Answer (score 2):

Вот так я Perl-ом стартую/останавливаю lighttpd. Может, поможет.

```
C:\x\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -h start /bin/bash -l -c "/cygdrive/c/do/scripts/lighttpd.pl"
```

Подрихтуйте последний параметр.